Why don't we account for rotation when counting number of triangles on a circle?
Say for example you have 6 points placed evenly on a circle
(e.g. sample picture below).

The number of triangles that can be formed using those 6 points is $6 \choose 3$. I understand this, but it just occurred to me why don't we divide by 6 to account for rotation? For instance, in our calculation $6 \choose 3$ we could've chosen the bottom 3 points or could've chosen the top 3 points, but either one is the same as the other just rotated $180^\text{o}$, so wouldn't that mean we're overcounting?

"either one is the same as the other just rotated $180^\circ$" the problem here is that the original question asks for the "number of triangles that can be formed by using these $6$ points", and it does not explicitly that triangles are the same if one can be rotated on to the other. Now, it can be argued that (1) the question, as written, distinguishes triangles which don't have the exact same set of vertices, OR (2) the question is ambiguous, and if you received it in an exam you should be asking the person who set the question about the rotation issue.

@SarveshRavichandranIyer To clarify, this wasn't really a question but more of a "thought experiment" that occurred when I was trying to find alternate ways to solve a problem and happened to (over?)think about this. Going back to what you said, are you saying that it's more of semantic/wording technicality? By that logic, wouldn't that mean there's no point in accounting for rotation in a typical round table seating arrangement problem since it can be argued that each one is different?

It seems to me that the phrase "number of triangles that can be formed", in the absence of any contrary specification, is intended to represent that two triangles are the same if and only if they each have the same 3 vertex points.  That is, in general, without an explicit specification, I would not expect the problem composer to intend that two triangles are the same if and only if they are congruent to each other.

@user2661923 Thanks, that makes sense

A large number of combinatorics problems involve looking at a quantity in at least two different ways. Often this results in either a proof or an identity.
In your case, you correctly state that $6 \choose 3$ is the number of ways we could choose a triangle simply from the vertices. Of course, this is not the only way, as you point out. Another way to count this would be to choose the vertices first, then rotate the  triangle around the center, accounting for how many ways you can rotate that and adding all these together.
The general principle to study here may be Burnside's lemma. You can count on it.

Thanks, I'll try to study that. It kind of reminds me the keychain with it's rotations and flips. However, I'm still confused why we don't account for rotation in the $6 \choose 3$ answer. I get that there's alternate ways to solve the problem that directly factor in the ways you can rotate, but why don't we account for rotation after we do $6 \choose 3$?

Typically the assumption is that each vertex is labeled. Therefore if it's not you are solving a totally different problem.

what do you mean why? we just don't account for rotation in $6 choose 3$ because it does not matter! you just choose three. any three from the set. doesn't matter where they are. still a triangle.

@KonradSzałwiński I see, so if they weren't labeled would that mean there would only be 4 triangles (i.e. the rotations do matter)?

@vallev Yes I understand that 3 points define a triangle, but what I was trying to ask was why don't we count 2 triangles as the same if they can be rotated to each other. Like I said in my post, if you choose the 3 bottom points from the set to form a triangle, it's the same as choosing the top 3 points to form a triangle and rotating it by 180
